# SELinux: How to add a new security context?

Tags: redhat, selinux

I'm new to SELinux and am trying to add a new security context (label) to test denial. To do this, I try changing a filew to a new context:

```
chcon -t new_t test
```

But it fails with "Invalid argument". How do I add the new type "new_t"?

Comment: chcon can only apply existing contexts to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example for how to create a new type is at http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PackagingDrafts/SELinux#Creating_new_types

Once you have build the module (`make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile`) and inserted it into SELinux (`semodule -i foobar.pp`) then you can `chcon -t foobar_t test`.